# iOS: CALayer shadow only rectangular?

Tags: ios, calayer

For the shadow properties on the CALayer, is that only rectangular and particular to the layer only? That is, with quartz I can set shadow while doing a fill path on some arbitrary path. Can I do that with CALayer's shadow properties? I do not think so but I want a confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're targeting iOS 3.2 or later then you can use any path you want, but people often miss it because it's in iOS but not in OS X. Check out the [shadowPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/shadowPath) property, which lets you set a specific path for each individual layer.

Also, if you're going to use shadows, it's definitely a good idea to enable [shouldRasterize](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/shouldRasterize) if possible; it makes a huge performance difference.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can can use the **shadowPath** property on your CALayer to set a custom shadow.  Here is an example:

```
[shadowDepth.layer setMasksToBounds:NO ];
[shadowDepth.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor blackColor ] CGColor ] ];
[shadowDepth.layer setShadowOpacity:0.5 ];
[shadowDepth.layer setShadowRadius:6.0 ];
[shadowDepth.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake( 0 , 0 ) ];
[shadowDepth.layer setShouldRasterize:YES ];
UIBezierPath * depthShadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath ];
[depthShadowPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake( 40 , 140 ) ];
[depthShadowPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake( shadowDepth.frame.size.width - 40 , 140 ) ];
[depthShadowPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake( shadowDepth.frame.size.width + 20 , shadowDepth.frame.size.height + 40 ) ];
[depthShadowPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake( -10 , shadowDepth.frame.size.height + 40 ) ];
[depthShadowPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake( 40 , 140 ) ];
[shadowDepth.layer setShadowPath:[depthShadowPath CGPath ] ];
```

I did a post on this along with some tips to optimize the performance hit to you application.  Check it out here: [CALayer Shadows](http://d3signerd.com/deep-dive-into-calayer-shadows/)